# How can I connect to deegree (localhost)?

Tags: qgis, wms, deegree, localhost

I have deegree version 3.4.16 running on 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost). I want to connect QGIS version 3.10.5-A Coruña to deegree (localhost).

I have set the following parameters in "Create a New WMS/WMTS Connection":
Name = deegree2
URL = 127.0.0.1:8080 (or localhost:8080, both tried)

The following error message appears:

`"Failed to download capabilities. Download of capabilities failed. Protocol "" is unknown`

What is missing? What went wrong

Comment: The error message says that protocol is needed, in this case the protocol is http. Try `http://127.0.0.1:8080`. But I guess, be reading https://download.deegree.org/documentation/3.4.15/html/#anchor-configuration-wms, that the url should contain also `/services/wms`. Or even something about your workspace, like in this `http://deegree3-demo.deegree.org/utah-workspace/services`.

Comment: @user30184 - that's an answer not a comment

Answer (score 1):

As user @user30184 already pointed out, the complete endpoint URL of a deegree WMS shall include the request context and service name such as `services/wms`.

The general request scheme is as follows:
`<protocol>://<host>:<port>/<deegree_webapp_name>/services/<service_name>`
where

- `protocol` can be either http or https
- `host` can be the hostname or IP address, such as localhost
- `port` the port number of the Servlet container running deegree, e.g. 8080
- `deegree_webapp_name` the filename of the deegree webapp deployed in the Servlet container, such as deegree-webservice (you may not add .war at the end!)
- `service_name` as the file name of the deegreeWMS configuration file in the active workspace, check the deegree workspace documentation in https://download.deegree.org/documentation/current/html/#_the_deegree_workspace for more information how to configure deegree WMS

Here is a complete example endpoint URL of a deegree WMS from the deegree demo site:
https://demo.deegree.org/utah-workspace/services/wms

For your case it may be http://localhost:8080/deegree-webservices/services/wms

Check the name of the web app and the name of the deegreeWMS configuration file. You can do this by opening http://localhost:8080/deegree-webservices in your browser, and click on the configuration element "web services > services" on the left side of the deegree admin console. Select the clickable "Capabilities" element and in a new browser tab the WMS capabilities document should be displayed. Copy the complete URL to QGIS.